# Issue parsing multiple positional arguments

Tags: python, arguments, argparse

I must be missing something really obvious, but I can't for the life of me spot it.

```py
import argparse


def parse_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Copies selected files.")
    parser.add_argument(
        "-c", "--checksum", type=bool, default=False
    )
    parser.add_argument("source")
    parser.add_argument("target")
    return parser.parse_args()


def main():
    args = parse_args()
    print(args.checksum, args.source, args.target)


main()
```

```
>python file_proc.py source1 target1
False source1 target1
```

So far, so good.

```
>python file_proc.py -c source1 target1
usage: file_proc.py [-h] [-c CHECKSUM] source target
file_proc.py: error: the following arguments are required: target
```

Now, why doesn't it output `True source1 target1`? It must be right there in front of me, but I need another pair of eyes.

Thanks!

Comment: The `type` parameter is supposed to be a function, something that will transform the input string into a desired value. You have to write your own if you want to interpret strings like "yes" or "no" as `True/False` booleans.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument declaration for `--checksum` means that *following* `-c`/`--checksum`, an actual boolean is passed in. For example, `--checksum yes` would "enable" the checksum; due to how `bool` interprets strings, *any* argument other than the empty string evaluates to `True`.

Use the [`store_true`/`store_false` action](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#action) to define an argument-less flag that is toggled on/off by being mentioned.

```py
    parser.add_argument(
        "-c", "--checksum", action='store_true'
    )
```

Comment: I know it was something basic! It's meant to be a switch argument, so I indeed needed `action='store_true'`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The way you've coded basically means, that if you are passing `-c`, then you need to pass a `bool` in the args as well.

Hence your statement:

```
>python file_proc.py source1 target1
False source1 target1
```

works fine, because you didn't pass `-c`. So, it printed `False`.

But when you pass `-c` in the command-line, it needs another variable to be passed in argument. So do this:

```
>python file_proc.py -c d source1 target1
True source1 target1
```

This means a `bool` was passed as an argument, hence it prints `True`.